# What does "play with your toy’s toys" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The Law of Demeter (“talk only to your friends”) is a good place to start, but think about it this way: you can play with your toys, with toys that you make, and with toys that someone gives you. You don't ever, ever play with your toy’s toys.

Source: The Thoughtworks Anthology

What could the last sentence mean? Could a toy have a toy? Assuming a toy means "A toy is an item that is used in play", a toy can never have a toy, so one cannot play with a toy’s toys (it's physically not possible).

The context is object oriented programming.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com) as it is not a question about the English language (the question could be equally posed in any language).

Comment: Presumably that's why the quoted passage says you never do it!

Comment: This problem depends on the ambiguousness of language. _Toys' toys_ could mean 'toys merely associated, in the sense that they mirror the toy - human association,  with other toys representing humans' (eg a toy hoop for a model of a boy). But it _could_ mean 'those things which the toys have chosen / made to use as toys' (obviously describing an impossibility, but referenced here). But this is probably off-topic as it stands, as the source is not necessarily a reliable source of sensible usage (or well-thought-out concepts).

Comment: I don't know that the non-programmers here will understand the context neccessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, the context being OOP.

Comment: @Mitch lol! No, it belongs on [SoftwareEngineering.SE].

Comment: @jpmc [The Model Village - a miniature version of Bourton-on-the-water located -in- Bourton-on-the-water](https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Model+Village/@51.8832459,-1.7564767,18z)

Comment: Unless for “toy” it refers to “sexual partners, both animated or inanimated”

Comment: In this context, it likely refers to you only interfacing with an object, and not directly with objects contained within those objects. If the parent object wants you to play with those, it should expose methods to do so. This is really better asked in programming.SE. And you're studying old stuff--look into dependency injection and functional programming.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Toys absolutely can have toys. For example, this “Barbie Kelly Playroom” comes with stuffed animals, dolls, a play kitchen, and UNO for Kelly (Barbie’s sister and a toy):

[image: Barbie playhouse]

In this case, it would be *possible* to play with Kelly’s toys directly (with the exception of UNO, which is almost certainly just a box). However, what you’re supposed to do is have *Kelly* play with her toys.

Comment: This makes sense, I would never have considered such a scenario, thanks.

Comment: Definitely still a strange wording, since I would consider that playing with my toys and having them play with toys as I play with them is still really me playing with the toy's toys.  It's just a really strange analogy because toys have no agency of their own to play with toys, so any instance of a toy playing with their toys is really you playing with the toy's toys.

Comment: @JMac: It's thinking at two levels of abstraction at once, a necessary skill for programmers. I can see how it's hard to get.

Comment: @Joshua I'm not talking about how "hard it is to get".  I'm talking about it's failure as an analogy.  If your toys have toys, it's hard to think of a scenario where you're _not_ supposed to play with them; so saying "You don't play with your toy's toys" is utter nonsense.  That's exactly what you do with your toy's toys, because your toys definitely aren't going to start playing with their toys themselves.

Comment: @JMac In this analogy, the play you are engaged in is _imagining_ that your toys are real people with the agency and ability to play with their own toys. (Even if you're the one physically moving them about, they still only move because your toys "wanted" them to.) Without adding that layer of imagination, all the "toy's toys" are a bunch of tiny, low quality pieces of badly molded plastic that _you_ probably wouldn't bother to play with at all.

Comment: @JMac It's not a _great_ analogy, but it's not horrible either since as an OOP programmer, you're often the one responsible for both the implementation of the "toy" and also the "toy's toy", but you have to mentally restrict yourself from relying on the details of the implementation of one when you create the other, lest you make a rats nest of unnecessary interdependence. _You_ shouldn't care about playing with your toy's toy, no matter how much your toy "likes" playing with it.

Comment: @jmbpiano I still consider it terrible because you absolutely do, contrary to what they suggest, play with your toy's toys.  You can add layers of abstraction to it like you're doing, saying that you don't _imagine_ that you're playing with your toy's toys; but it doesn't change what you actually _do_.  If your toys have toys, and you want those toys to play with those toys, you _have_ to play with your toy's toys, and cannot let your toys play with their toys themselves.  It cannot happen, even if you can _pretend_ it does.

Comment: @JMac but that's the exact in programming; _you_ are still calling the code in the "toy's toy", just indirectly. You just have to remember that while that is physically what you're doing, it'll be a weird and ultimately not very fun game if you don't maintain the extra layer of imagination.

Comment: @JMac What analogy would you use if you had toys, each with their own set of assigned toys, but you had to discipline yourself to not play with your toy's toys directly? In OOP, the distinction between toy and toy's toy is completely arbitrary. But if you don't discipline yourself with how you play with them, you will end up with a tangled mess. While the analogy is hard to understand, to be honest I don't know how better way to express it.

Comment: @Tezra I wouldn't call them toys _at all_, because it doesn't really make a clear analogy.  Is a _toy_ some other concept in OOP besides the English word?

Comment: @Erik It still seems terribly confusing to me and makes no sense to use a toy as this analogy.  Playing with the toy's toy is still _literally_ the thing you're doing, even if that act involves making the toy play with it's toy.  If I were playing with the playroom in this answer, I would still absolutely say "I'm playing with my toy's toys".  I could _also_ say "My toys are playing with their toys" in the make-believe sense; but the former statement is still completely accurate, so the use of "toys" as an analogy just makes no sense.  You _can_ do that very thing in a very literal sense.

Comment: You can pick your friends, and you can pick your nose, but you should never pick your friend's nose.

Answer (score 56):

This question seems to be about programming rather than English language, and would probably be better on Stack Overflow…  That said, I'll answer it anyway:

---

Without a context, this doesn't make much sense. But working backwards from the fact that the context is object-oriented programming, and thus kind of 'reverse-engineering' the question, if you will:

It's saying that in OOP, in your implementation of a class, you can access and modify properties of instances of the class you are implementing itself (*"your toys, toys you make"*) and data that's passed into instances of that class such as when it is instantiated ("*toys you're given*"). But you shouldn't modify private properties of other objects directly, even if you own those objects ("*your toys' toys*") because that can result in unexpected or undefined behaviour.

It's a pretty bad analogy.

Comment: "pretty bad analogy".. Ah, that explains things. I'm a programmer and I couldn't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: Maybe a better analogy is [food](https://makeameme.org/meme/salad-you-mean-0q3jws) rather than toys.

Comment: This is the appropriate meaning

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I don't see how "boys' toys" would work in the quotation in the question; how would you then interpret the sentence?

Comment: I am not a programmer, so is OOP a computer language? EDIT It's *object oriented programming*. I think you have posted the right answer because I cannot make head nor tail of it :)

Answer (score 1):

[Laurel's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/502287/233327) explains the the meaning of the pure english part of the analogy, but for completeness I just want to add what this analogy means in OOP terms.

If you think of Objects (class instances) as toys, and you yourself are also a toy (the logic of a class object); you can play with your toys (globals/properties of that class), with toys that you make (new/declared variables), and with toys that someone gives you (parameters). You don't ever, ever play with your toy’s toys (the internal globals/properties of the previously listed Objects you can play with).

And like the doll set in Laurel's answer, as the programmer technically all of the "toys" are really "your toys". In OOP, it is perfectly valid to play with your toy's toys. If you do however, you wouldn't be using the toys in the way they were intended to be used.

Comment: Apart from affording English less respect than oop, this would seem to be a perfect answer, but shows that it is primarily an OOP question.

Comment: Upvoted because I understood the explanation. It also explains why the question generated so many views.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have said, it's a badly worded analogy, around the fact that you shouldn't directly interact with items you don't directly own (or have been given permission to interact with).

A better analogy would be: you have a sandwich, and your partner has a sandwich.  You can eat your sandwich if you want, but you shouldn't eat your partner's sandwich without their permission.  Otherwise, there may be trouble when they get and try to eat it...